# Question about a determinant property I encountered in a question.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Here's the question: 
let $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ such that $AB=|A|I$ and $|(2A)^2(A^t)^{-1}B|=16$ then $|A|=?$ 
I wanted to ask about how to deal with the information that $AB=|A|I$, can I just $|AB|=||A|I|=|A|$? am I allowed to do that? 
From the other information I got that $4^3|A||B|=16$ so $|AB|=\frac {1}{4}$. 
So what I said was $|A|=\frac {1}{4}$, but the answer was $|A|=(\frac{1}{4})^{\frac {1}{3}}$, so I think I have a miss understanding about how to calculate $||A|I|$. 
Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Be careful, the good formula is $\det(\lambda M)=\lambda^n \det(M)$, where $n$ is the dimension of the matrix... So $\det(\det(A)I)= ...$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks for the comment, Yes I know that formula, but how can I apply it in $||A|I|$, what I did was : $||A|I|$=$||A||*|I|=|A|$, that seems wrong but I can't see why.

Comment: $\det(A)$ is a number here ! So if you want to put it out from the $\det$, you have to put it out with the good power. Apply the formula I gave with $M=I$ and $\lambda=\det(A)$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks alot, all clear now, I appreciate the help :).

Answer (score 2):

From $AB=|A|\operatorname{Id}$ and from the fact that $A$ is a $3\times3$ matrix, you get that$$|A||B|=\bigl||A|\operatorname{Id}\bigr|=|A|^3.$$And from the fact that $\left|(2A)^2\left(A^T\right)^{-1}B\right|=16$, you get that$$64|A|^2\frac1{|A|}|B|=16\left(\iff|A||B|=\frac14\right).$$So, $|A|^3=\frac14$, and therefore $|A|=\frac1{\sqrt[3]4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$|kA|=k^3|A|$, if $A$ is $3 \times 3$.similarly $||A|I|=|A|^3$.

Comment: @Z Ahmed Thanks alot, this clears it, wonderful trick to know :). Appreciate the answer.